# Could not get sum of each row in a column in php mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, sum

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J53m2.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mgx7y.png)I have a database table having multiple cols and data in many rows. I want to get sum of all data of all the data in each row and place in a col 'Total'. However, Grand total is showing in each row and not the total of each row.

I am presenting the code as below

```
<?php 
include 'config.php';
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
$add=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT Col1,    Col2,   Col3,   Col4,   
sum(Col1 +  Col2 +  Col3 +  Col4) AS Total, SUM(Col1), SUM(Col2), 
SUM(Col3), SUM(Col4)
from DistrictData WHERE District = 'District1' ");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($add))
{
$Total = $row['Total'];
$SUM1=$row['SUM(Col1)'];
$SUM2=$row['SUM(Col2)'];    
$SUM3=$row['SUM(Col3)'];
$SUM4=$row['SUM(Col4)'];
$Total2= $SUM1 + $SUM2+ $SUM3+ $SUM4  ;
}
}
$sql="SELECT * FROM DistrictData WHERE District = 'District1'"; $counter = 0;
$result = $con->query($sql);
?>
<body>
<table >
<tr>
<td>Sr No.</td>
<td>Deptt</td>
<td>Data Description</td>
<td>Unit</td>
<td>Year</td>
<td>Blocks in District</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Total</td>
<td>Col1</td>
<td>Col2</td>
<td>Col3</td>
<td>Col4</td>
</tr>
<?php
while($rows = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
?>
<tr> 
<td><?php echo ++$counter; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $rows['Data']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $rows['Description']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $rows['Unit']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $rows['Year']; ?></td>
<td> <?php echo $Total ?></td>
<td><?php echo $rows['Col1']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $rows['Col2']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $rows['Col3']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $rows['Col4']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
<tr>
<td>Total:</td>
<td> <?php echo $Total2 ?></td>
<td> <?php echo $SUM1 ?></td>
<td> <?php echo $SUM2 ?></td>
<td> <?php echo $SUM3 ?></td>
<td> <?php echo $SUM4 ?></td>
</tr>
</table>
<?php    
$con->close();
?>
```

[Output of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOYPc.png)

Please suggest any changes in the code so that I could get the sum for each row in Total Column.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use this query for row sum of column elements

```
 SELECT Col1+Col2+Col3+Col4 as I_want_this_figure from DistrictData
```

Comment: Thanks Aqid for your promt reply... However, when I use "SELECT Col1+Col2+Col3+Col4 as I_want_this _figure from DistrictData)" the result is 0 (zero), and when I use "Sum(Col1+Col2+Col3+Col4)"  the result is 391 (GTotal as earlier) in each row. So, could not get the desired result in the col (I_want_this _figure). Pl see "Output of the code".

Answer (score 0):

Note that a normalised environment would typically look more like this...

```
sr_no district_block val
    1              1   5
    1              2   6
    1              3   5
    1              4   8
    2              1 226
    2              2 112
    2              3   4
    2              4   5
    3              1   2 
    3              2   7
    3              3   3
    3              4   8
```

... where (sr_no,district_block) are components of a PRIMARY KEY

Answer (score 0):

Use Allies after every Sum() as something.
You will get last result when you take away total from while loop.
do your first Query under 2nd Query and pass the ID as parameter.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){

   $total_query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT Col1,    Col2,   Col3,   Col4,   
   SUM(Col1 +  Col2 +  Col3 +  Col4) as Total from DistrictData WHERE id='row[yourID]'");

   $total_result = mysqli_fetch_array($total_query);

   NOW you can populate your data here

}
```

Hope this will help you.